# How to build a python project into a .deb executable with Pypi requirements included?

Tags: python, build, deb

I want to build a python project into a .deb executable, i'm using stdeb but it dont fit well to projects that use PyPi dependencies. There is a way to use stdeb with venv to encapsulate the dependencies in the build?

I've already tryied to use vdist, dh-virtualenv and the install_requires on the setup.py to solve my problem with dependencies on build but not luck.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/). I used it to create an executable for windows for an application that used *pandas* and *reportlab* and they were nicely bundled and everything worked as expected no need to install anything when deploying. I'm guessing from the documentation that it will also work on Linux.

Comment: I read the Doc and not seems to have support for .deb build.

Comment: Certainly, but correct me if I'm wrong. Your question is about creating a Debian installer for bundling the dependencies and distribute the software as an installer, but wouldn't distributing an executable save you and the user some overhead?